# plsql, modify cursor returning from function

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I have function get_header in package "MyPackage":

```
function get_header(
    i_in          in integer
)
return sys_refcursor;  -- two columns 'DATA_1' and 'DATA_2'
```

This function return cursor with 2 string columns with unixtime. I would like to change/add two columns with converted unixtime to "human time". Is there any option to create anonymous block with calling this function, and next modify result by add two more columns and next return modified cursor with two more columns?

I would like to do STH like this:

```
DECLARE
   out_cursor MyPackage.Ref_cursor;

BEGIN
   OPEN out_cursor
   FOR SELECT a.*, unix2date(a.DATA_1), unix2date(a.DATA_2) 
       FROM MyPackage.get_header(1) a 
       WHERE DATA_1 = '1423046354';

   RETURN new result or new cursor;
END;
```

Comment: No, you can't change a cursor after it has been opened.

Comment: This in on PRODUCTION. I can not change function, I can call it only. Maybe not change cursor, but create new copy with two additional columns?

Comment: You can't return anything from an anonymous block, but you can get data out via bind variables; how will you be executing it, and how will you be consuming the result? Does the cursor have multiple rows or a single row?

Comment: This cursor has multiple rows. I call this function in PLSQL Developer via TEST:
[code]
    begin
      -- Call the function
      :result := MyPackage.get_header(i_in => :i_in );
    end;
[/code]

Comment: @zgrzewka - but what will you do with `result`, both when testing and for real - do the dates actually have to be columns in the result set or can they be converted later, either in other PL/SQL or client/application code? Your example restricts to a single `data_1` value, so do you ultimately only want one row of data in `result`? Add can you create new objects/types or are you restricted to querying and anonymous blocks only?

Comment: I am restricted to querying and anonymous blocks only. It can be converted later. I just wanna see this dates converted to human dates. I have many rows in results. PL/SQL Developer let me see cursor results. But I want to modify somehow this results to see columns with unix time as a human time. It can be in extra columns or by modifing this column, I just want to see cenverted time.

Comment: I wanna see all this column + DATA_1 and DATA_2 converted to human date.

Comment: Oh, and on a PRODUCTION we already have unix2date function, that I can use.